# convert varbinary to xml C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

i have A C# winforms Application that save files to sqlserver Database (2014)
to varbinary(MAX) field

Function To save

```
 byte[] Bytefile;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DataHelper.GetConnection()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Delete  T_Articale_Files where Artricle_id=" + ID, conn);

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(varFilePath))
            {

                using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(varFilePath, file), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        Bytefile = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                    }
                }


                using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO T_Articale_Files (Artricle_id,FileName,FileData) Values(@ID,@FileName,@File)", conn))
                {
                    sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 10).Value = ID;
                    sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = Bytefile;
                    sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Function to Retrieve

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DataHelper.GetConnection()))
        //   using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,FileName FROM T_Articale_Files WHERE Artricle_id = @varID", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varID", varID);
            dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                using (var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT FileData FROM T_Articale_Files WHERE id = @ID", conn))
                {
                    sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", item["id"]);

                    using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader())
                        while (sqlQueryResult.Read())
                        {

                            var blob = new Byte[(sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                            sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                            using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(varPathToNewLocation, item["FileName"].ToString()), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                                fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                        }
                }
            }

        }
```

that work fine
Now i have asked to convert the database to XML for PCs that does not have Connection to server

Function to Convert to XML

```
 var xmlFileData = "";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        var tables = new[] { "V_Articale", "T_Articale", "T_City", "T_Classification", "T_Country", "T_Locations", "T_milishia", "T_Search", "T_statistics", "T_TerrorGroups", "T_Tribes", "T_Users", "T_Articale_Files" };
        foreach (var table in tables)
        {

            var query = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
            SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(table);
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            if(table== "T_Articale_Files")
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Byte[] file = GetBytes(item["FileData"].ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        xmlFileData = ds.GetXml();
```

it work fine except for the Binary  filed
it is converted to text when

The output XML

```
<T_Articale_Files>
<id>6</id>
<Artricle_id>1013</Artricle_id>
<FileName>falcon banner.jpg</FileName>
<FileData>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4QleRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAAUA</FileData>
```

when try to convert it back to image it gives me 1kb file with the string not the actual image

is there special convert for the binary field
Please Advise

Thank you

Edit Problem Solved thanks to @grek40 
Solution Convert to XML

```
  var xmlstream = new StringWriter();
        ds.WriteXml(xmlstream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        string xmlWithSchema = xmlstream.ToString();
```

where ds is a dataset

Convert back to file

```
  private  void databaseFileRead(int varID, string varPathToNewLocation)
    {
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(XMLpath);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables["T_Articale_Files"];
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = "Artricle_id=" + varID;

        if (dv.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRowView item in dv)
            {
                byte[] stringArray = (byte[])(item["FileData"]);
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Filepath, item["FileName"].ToString()), stringArray  ); // save image to disk


            }

        }
```

Comment: What if you don't .ToString() your FileData? Byte[] file = GetBytes(item["FileData"]); instead of Byte[] file = GetBytes(item["FileData"].ToString());

Comment: With binary data never use ToString() which always screws up the data.  It is better to use Encoding.UTF8 with methods GetBytes() or GetString();  A string/char is two bytes with a protected property that indicates if char is one or two bytes.   When you use ToString() method it makes can make mistakes determining if a char is one ro two char.  Using UTF8 will force every char to one byte.

Comment: if you are talking about  if(table== "T_Articale_Files")
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Byte[] file = GetBytes(item["FileData"].ToString());
                }
            } i commented that code and used the method with out it

Comment: if you asking what GetBytes is   static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }

Comment: @Maher Khalil No it was actually in your 'Convert to XML' function. When you convert your varbinary(MAX) to a Byte[]

Comment: this part i have commented because i didn't know how to implement it  in Convert to xml  if(table== "T_Articale_Files")
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Byte[] file = GetBytes(item["FileData"].ToString());
                }
            }

Comment: @MaherKhalil I was just thinking, that you in your 'Function To save' read your files as byte[], and then save them in your blob as byte[]. But when you want to convert the DataTable to XML you convert the blob byte[] to string. What happens if you just cast item["FileData"] to byte[]?

Comment: it returns Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String[]'

Comment: Can you show the code where you read the data back from xml into your data structure?

Comment: it is the same Function to Retrieve  except i change the data source from sql to XML   ds.ReadXml(path);   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt = ds.Tables["T_Articale_Files"];   DataView dv = new DataView(dt);  dv.RowFilter = "Artricle_id=" + varID;    if (dv.Count > 0)
            { foreach (DataRowView item in dv)  {byte[] stringArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item["FileData"].ToString());
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Filepath, item["FileName"].ToString()), stringArray  ); // save image to disk                   
                }               
            }

Comment: This comment is mostly unreadable. Please edit your xml retrieve function into the question. I'm suspicious of things like `byte[] stringArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item["FileData"].ToString());` which are clearly **not the same** as in your sql retrieve.

Comment: i did read it so what is the changes will be made to fix retrieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a reversible string encoding of binary data, you could use Base64 encoding

```
public byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(str);
}

public string ByteArrToString(byte[] byteArr)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);
}
```

transform bytes to string which is stored in xml and restore bytes from string on usage.

Initially the data are correctly written as xml. The problem is most likely with the retrieve function. Since the xml doesn't contain schema information, it will treat the `<FileData>` as text unless it is instructed differently.

In order to allow correct re-reading, you need either a pre-defined schema when reading or you have to write the schema with the tables:

```
dataSet.WriteXml(filenameOrStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
// later read the xml and it will respect the schema information
dataSet.ReadXml(filenameOrStream);
```

A small sample of the different aspects:

```
var sourceDataSet = new DataSet();
var sourceTable = new DataTable("TableWithBinary");

sourceDataSet.Tables.Add(sourceTable);

sourceTable.Columns.Add("Id");
sourceTable.Columns.Add("File", typeof(byte[]));

sourceTable.Rows.Add(1, new byte[] { 1, 0, 2 });
sourceTable.Rows.Add(2, new byte[] { 1, 3, 2 });

// write option 1
string schema = sourceDataSet.GetXmlSchema();
string getxml = sourceDataSet.GetXml();

// write option 2
var writexmlstream = new StringWriter();
sourceDataSet.WriteXml(writexmlstream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
string writexmlWithSchema = writexmlstream.ToString();

// read wrong (missing schema)
var targetCorrupted = new DataSet();
targetCorrupted.ReadXml(new StringReader(getxml));

// read correct with schema in every xml file
var targetFromXmlWithSchema = new DataSet();
targetFromXmlWithSchema.ReadXml(new StringReader(writexmlWithSchema));

// read correct with separate schema definition and data
var targetFromXml = new DataSet();
targetFromXml.ReadXmlSchema(new StringReader(schema));
targetFromXml.ReadXml(new StringReader(getxml));
```

Comment: @MaherKhalil You showed your output XML, where the `<FileData>` section is corrupted... just convert the binary data for `<FileData>` to string using `ByteArrToString` when you generate the XML.

Comment: the <fileData> is generated using Function to Convert to XML (Select * from Table) now the question is what special treatment do i have to do with the table with binary table

Comment: @MaherKhalil Actually, if you don't do anything, is there really a problem? Please inspect the DataType for the FileData column. If it is `byte[]`, then ds.GetXml() should automatically have a suitable data representation. Maybe your problem is more with reading the data and not so much with writing them...

Comment: 1- the data is save to the column correct because i can convert the column back to image , 2- the convert to xml run and convert the binary column to the above xml representation , 3- i use function to retrieve  to get the image back as file IMPOTANT NOTE : function to retrieve get the correct image if used in the actual table but it does not work when getting the data from XML ; So the problem either in saving the bytes to XML or function to retrieve should be modified

Comment: Guess i was to fixed on the writing part at first, should be better now. Note, that you can also chose to write the XML schema separately for each table structure (don't include it for every data file) and then load the data.. gonna edit once more.

Comment: i will try that But does this approach require a different Function to Retrieve or the above will work (when i change the data source from sql to xml)

Comment: @MaherKhalil I think you misunderstand the concept of stackoverflow a bit. My answer shows multiple ways to read/write the xml as `string`, as `TextReader`/`TextWriter` and there are also overloads of the used functions that accept a `Stream` or a filename. I honestly don't care which way you chose to interact with your files and I'm not going to write your specific code - thats what you and others are paid for, right?

Answer (score 0):

The standard format for **binary *within* XML** is `base64`. I do not think, that there's something wrong with the above...

You must bear in mind, that several characters are forbidden within XML. You cannot just stuff binary data between two XML tags. If there was the numeric code for a `<` (or some other forbidden character) somewhere in your binary by chance, it would break.

The string you show looks pretty much like a base64 code.

Try this

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)='Hello World with forbidden characters (< & >)';
DECLARE @binary VARBINARY(MAX) = CAST(@string AS VARBINARY(MAX));
DECLARE @xml XML=(SELECT @string AS string, @binary AS bin FOR XML PATH('test'));

SELECT @xml;
```

--The result (with encoded entities and the binary implicitly converted to base64)

```
<test>
  <string>Hello World with forbidden characters (&lt; &amp; &gt;)</string>
  <bin>SGVsbG8gV29ybGQgd2l0aCBmb3JiaWRkZW4gY2hhcmFjdGVycyAoPCAmID4p</bin>
</test>
```

--Now we read from the XML (entities are re-coded, the binary is represented as a HEX-string and this can be re-casted to the former `VARCHAR(MAX)`

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/test/string)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TheStringAsIs
      ,@xml.value('(/test/bin)[1]','varbinary(max)') AS TheStringAsBinary_HEX
      ,CAST(@xml.value('(/test/bin)[1]','varbinary(max)') AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ReConverted
```

The results

```
The string *as-is*:  Hello World with forbidden characters (< & >)  
binary data HEX:     0x48656C6C6F20576F726C64207769746820666F7262696464656E206368617261637465727320283C2026203E29   
ReConverted:         Hello World with forbidden characters (< & >)
```

Comment: this is sql function not C# second it is a file i don't know what charters will be when it is converted

Comment: @MaherKhalil this does not matter ... The principle is the same. And binary can store literally everything. But it must be encoded to fit into xml